# How to lint for Typescript compilation issues?

Tags: typescript, tslint, pre-commit-hook, husky, lint-staged

Take the following Typescript arrow function:

```
/**
 * Returns a probably unique component name.
 * 
 * @param baseName a suggested name to make unique.
 * @returns a probably unique name.
 */
export const getUniqueComponentName = (
  baseName
): string => {
  return baseName + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000000)
}
```

When Typescript is configured in `tsconfig.json` as such:

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```

This correctly results in a compilation error:

> [ts] Parameter 'baseName' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Visual Studio Code is also smart enough to inform you about this issue during development.

My goal is to create a precommit git hook that prevents such errors from ending up in version control. I tried to do this with `tslint`, `husky` and `lint-staged` using this `npm script`:

```
"lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json"
```

However, this does not result in the compilation error showing up by tslint. It is silently ignored.

I then tried to add a rule in tslint.json:

```
"typedef": [
      true,
      "arrow-parameter"
    ]
```

While this did make tslint complain, it also started to complain in anonymous arrow functions where the `tsc` compiler does not complain. In these arrow functions it should not be necessary to add types because the types were already set previously in the parent scope (they are inferred).

So basically, I would like for tslint to behave the same as tsc in this case. Anytime there is an error that would cause compilation to fail (such as the above arrow function), I would like to prevent the commit, but without actually compiling to Javascript. Is this possible?

Comment: Would running `tsc --noEmit` work? That is essentially running the static analyzer without generating JS.

Comment: @y2bd yes I confirmed that works; is that a recommended way of doing it? in addition to running tslint?

Comment: In my workflow I usually do a normal build and just discard the artifacts (as well as a separate lint stage). If you're in a situation where that's not preferable this seems completely fine.

Comment: @y2bd according to https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/412 it is not possible to have `lint-staged` run `tsc` only on the commited files. This is only possible if you don't pass in a `p` flag but then all config options are ignored. Also you cannot pass in the `paths` config as a command line argument, so not using `p` does not seem to be an option?

Comment: @y2bd I put up a 150 rep bounty if you could elaborate on my previous question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your best bet is to run `tsc --noEmit -p .` and filter the output for errors in the modified files.  For example, I saved the following script to `tsc-some-files`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A include_files
for f in "$@"; do
  include_files["${f#$PWD/}"]=1
done
node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit -p . | (
  status=0
  show_continuation=false
  while IFS='' read -r line; do
    case "$line" in
    (' '*)
      if $show_continuation; then
        echo "$line" >&2
      fi
      ;;
    (*)
      file="${line%%(*}"
      if [ -n "${include_files["$file"]}" ]; then
        show_continuation=true
        echo "$line" >&2
        status=1
      else
        show_continuation=false
      fi
      ;;
    esac
  done
  exit $status
)
```

and set `./tsc-some-files` as my `lint-staged` command, and it seemed to work.  (Writing this in a programming language other than bash, if desired, is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Keep in mind though that editing one file can introduce an error in another file (e.g., if you changed the type of something that the other file is using), so I'd urge you to get your project clean of TypeScript errors ASAP by whatever hacks necessary (as long as you mark them so you can search for them later) and then set your hook to require no errors in the whole project.  In fact, with respect to `noImplicitAny` in particular, when I migrated a JavaScript project to TypeScript several years ago, I wrote a script that inserted an explicit `any` everywhere there was an implicit `any` error, then I fixed the explicit `any`s at my leisure.  I can share the script if you're interested.

Comment: This will run tsc on the entire project, not just on the committed files

Comment: What is your concern?  Performance, or that there are existing errors in other files that you want to ignore until those files are next modified?

Comment: The second case mostly. The first one slightly :)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the script. I've tried integrating it with TS v3 and I'm getting weird errors like this one: `./scripts/ts-staged-files.sh: line 4: src/ui/Components/Select/Select.tsx: division by 0 (error token is "/Components/Select/Select.tsx")`

Comment: @okonetchnikov It looks like bash is trying to treat the filename as a string, which shouldn't happen if you copied the script correctly including the `declare -A` line.  Can you please publish a repository that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `-A` doesn’t work for me on Mac so I changed to `-a` assuming it’s the same.

Comment: @okonetchnikov That's your problem.  You'll need to either get a version of bash that supports `declare -A` or find another solution, such as rewriting the script in a programming language that is supported in your environment.  (I'm not interested in doing that work myself right now.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment, but anyone that is getting an error similar to

```
./scripts/ts-staged-files.sh: line 4: 
   src/ui/Components/Select/Select.tsx: division by 0 
  (error token is "/Components/Select/Select.tsx")
```

I made this small modification to Matt McCutchen's answer to fix it.

```
#!/bin/bash

include_files=()

for f in "$@"; do
  include_files+=("${f#$PWD/}")
done
```