# Specific tsconfig.json rules inside folder

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

How can I use an inner `config.json` in my Typescript project?

For clarity:

I have a root `/config.json` as following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2017",
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./app/",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true, 
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

I want to have a `/innerFolder/config.json` with the following:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  }
}
```

I'm doing that because I want to make a refactor on the team's code, but it's big and I don't want to change the all my files at once.

I want to do it folder-by-folder and "lock" the folder with the changes.

According to the documentation, the compiler looks up to a parent `tsconfig.json`, but not down for specific `tsconfig.json`.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I only needed the rules for strict checking, I was able to achieve it using `tslint`.

`extends` from `tslint` does exactly what I need, it goes down, overriding rules in inner directories.

Comment: how to set implicit any false in tslint rules , i'm in similar situation as yours where i only need this configuration for some inner folder only.

Comment: I guess you cannot do it. Only tsconfig has this rule, unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript 2.1 [added configuration inheritance](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9876) and this should now work the way you're using it.

Comment: Well, I tried it on my project (Typescript 4) and it didn’t work...

Answer (score 4):

Within a single project, there's no way to apply different compiler options to different files.  If your folders follow a simple dependency structure, you may be able to use multiple projects with [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).  Otherwise, you could write a script that runs `tsc` on the entire project twice (once with the stricter options and once with the looser options) and combines the errors from the first run on `innerFolder` and the errors from the second run on all other files; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51531201) for some inspiration on how to filter errors by filename.  This won't help with your IDE; there, you may have to just use the looser options.

Answer (score 0):

It should suffice to use:

```
tsc -p tsconfig.test.json
```

and set your "test" script to invoke that usage of tsc

see also: [How to exclude specific files in typescript only for the build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461649/how-to-exclude-specific-files-in-typescript-only-for-the-build)