# How to exclude specific files in typescript only for the build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, tsconfig

Is it possible to exclude all test files only for the build but use them with nodemon to run tests locally? When I exclude test files within the `tsconfig.json` file I get a typescript error that it can't find the types of the testing library like jest in my case.

> Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions
> for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.ts(2582)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {},
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am wondering since I guess the temporary transpiling is put into another folder than the build folder.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use two different tsconfig files, one for the tests and one for the production build.

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*"]
    },
    "strict": true,
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.prod.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig",
  "exclude": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.mock.ts"]
}
```

Then point tsc to the new config when running `tsc -p tsconfig.prod.json`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It's a good solution.