# Can you enable TypeScript strict mode on a per file?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to enable strict checks done by the TSC compiler (i.e. `--strict` et al.) file-by-file, say using a special comment? I'm working on an established Angular codebase that mostly doesn't take advantage of TS, and I'd like to have at least my own code be neater without also having to fix everybody else's code by turning the flag on for the whole project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not currently.  See [this open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28306); I don't expect the TypeScript team to get around to it any time soon.  One workaround might be to write a script that runs `tsc` with the stricter checks enabled and filters the output for the files you want; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51531201) for some prior art.

Comment: TIL: Someone created a [compiler plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28306#issuecomment-848699396). Seems to work so far (only tested the language server)